# jQuery select elements which contain specified item in an array data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have an element which I'd like to give a data attribute which contains a series of values, i.e., an `Array`. Then I'd like to be able to select it based on any of the values in that series. Something like this:

```
<div id="example" data-my-series='["foo", "bar"]'></div>
```

Then I was hoping to select it based on the fact that it has `"foo"` in it. I'm not really sure how I'd go about it, though. I know I'd do `$('div[data-my-series="foo"]')` if I wasn't taking this approach, but, obviously that's not the case. Any suggestions?

*Edit:* Also, how can I achieve the inverse of this? i.e., select an element which does *not* have `"foo"` in its `data-my-series`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out. The accepted answer will do substring matching and probably result in matches you didn't intend.

`$('[data-my-series*="foo"]')` will not just find `<div data-my-series="foo">` but will also include `<div data-my-series="foobar">` in the results

You should use ~ instead of * to do whole-word matching `$('[data-my-series~="foo"]')`. This will result in matching `foo` but not `foobar`

If you want multiple words in the data string, use spaces to separate them:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Comment: If you can provide an example showing why this is correct I'll accept your answer instead.

Comment: Consider the following:
`<div data-my-series="women"></div>
<div data-my-series="men"></div>`

Using `$('[data-my-series*="men"]')` will end up matching both `div.men` and `div.women` instead of just `div.men`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense if you use space delimiting.

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "[data-my-series*='foo']" )
```

Here ya go!

Comment: This. But also, as a side note, if you use the jQuery `.data()` method to change these values this method will no longer work to select the elements with updated values.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is very similar to what you are doing, just use the Attribute Contains Selector instead of the equals selector: `$('div[data-my-series*="foo"]')`

You can see more about it here:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Edit:

To answer the comment below, you can layer selectors in jQuery so take a look at the ":not()" selector. The usage would be `$('div:not([data-my-series*="foo"])')`. 
Make sure you don't put the `div` inside the `:not`. Also you will probably want to add `[data-my-series]` outside the `:not` as well to make sure you only select divs that have that data attribute.

Final product:
`$('div[data-my-series]:not([data-my-series*="foo"])')`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the link too. How can I do the inverse now? That is, select things which don't have `foo` in them. I didn't see something like that on the jQuery site you linked.

Comment: I added the answer to this question to my original answer.

Comment: Watch out. This example will do simple string matching and probably result in matches you didn't intend.

`$('[data-my-series*="foo"]')` will not just find `<div data-my-series="foo">` but will also include `<div data-my-series="foobar">` in the results